# Disabling USB debugging by default

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, lineageos

When I connect my LineageOS 16 (Android 9) device to my computer, USB debugging turns on by default. Even when locked. That doesn't seem safe, so I searched through my settings to change that. I turned off 'Android debugging' and revoked USB debugging authorizations, which seemed to be the end of it. But then I rebooted and the 'Tap to turn off USB debugging' notification comes on again immediately after reconnecting!

How do I disable USB debugging by default?

Comment: That does not sound like an official LineageOS release - may be it is a custom LineageOS based ROM that has been altered by the developer to always enable ADB?

Comment: I thought I was using an official OnePlus 3 build, but I'm not entirely sure now. My build number starts with 'lineage_oneplus3-userdebug 9'. Is that normal?

Comment: No, that is not normal. Seems like you installed a debug build. These builds are designed to be used on development devices only.

Comment: Oh okay, that's good to know. Can I switch to a release build without losing data? If yes, do I get them from the built-in updater or from https://download.lineageos.org/oneplus3?

Comment: I rifled through my Recycle Bin to see what the name of the archive I originally downloaded was, and it was `lineage-16.0-20190409-nightly-oneplus3-signed.zip`. So I do believe it wasn't a debug build.

Comment: I ended up going back to stock, but this bug might be interesting for people finding this thread later: https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/issues/308